# how do I shape my graphql backend response?

Tags: graphql

I am querying my graphql backend and need the response to have a flatten shape,

my query:

```
gql`
  {
    questions {
      edges {
         id
         title
         author: user {
          email
         }
      }
   }
  }
`
```

my response:

```
    '5d3eafb7889a135ff8cd950c': {
      id: '5d3eafb7889a135ff8cd950c',
      title: 's',
      author: {
        email: 'dggdfgdgfd@gmail.com',
        __typename: 'User'
      },
      __typename: 'Question'
    },
```

problem is with author, I need as a string instead of an object:

id: '5d3eafb7889a135ff8cd950c',
   title: 's',
   author: 'dggdfgdgfd@gmail.com'  // <===
  `

Comment: It is not possible to change the shape of the response in GraphQL (you can only rename fields like you are already doing for `user`/`author`). Not sure what you are passing the data to, but you could use a simple `map` to change the structure of the questions when needed.

Answer (score 2):

You have two options:

1) After getting the data from the GraphQL server, transform the data as you need to fit your needs.  A Javascript implementation might be:

```
function flattenGqlResponse (response) {
  return Object.keys(response).map((question) => {
    return {
      id: response[question].id,
      title: response[question].title,
      author: response[question].author.email
      }
    } 
  );
}
```

2) Flatten the structure in your GraphQL Resolver on your GraphQL Server.  Likely, you do not want to pursue this route based on what I see about your schema, unless your `User` object only has one field, that is `email`

Comment: Thank you, it did the trick...will add your answer to my javascript fundamental study stack...